# auto arrangement of div with different sizes and float

Tags: javascript, css

Hej folks!

I'm having a serious issue here. I working on a programm with an 3 column layout. Each colum width could be changed by move a slider. So far so easy.

In each Column i need to show many many different divs with information. Due to the possibilitay to resize the column i want the divs to float themselves to a minimal layout. The problem is the diffrent height of each block, but a image say more than thousand words:

http://web-tweaks.de/false.png

as you see there is a big space between the two left divs.
This is how i would like it to look:
http://web-tweaks.de/true.png

the height of the divs are total dynamic and its impossible to rearange then inside the code because many of them are created on the fly. (thous they are dragable for a rearrangement...).

this is the HTML part:

```
<div class="_content">
                <div class="_dt_floating_container">
                    <div class="_title">Stammdaten</div>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                </div>
                <div class="_dt_floating_container">
                    <div class="_title">Bankdaten</div>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                </div>
                <div class="_dt_floating_container">
                    <div class="_title">Stammdaten</div>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                    PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>PLACEHOLDER <br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the css:

```
._dt_floating_container {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

._dt_floating_container > ._title {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px; 
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfxEG/
if you resize the column size you will see the problem.

Is this even possible with pure CSS? It would be no problem to solve this in JS, i already have a complex window manager, but the easyer the better :)

i already tryed diffrent solutions like inline-block, float etc.
Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: If you want it to be totally dynamic (i.e. the structure rearranges itself to fit best into both the available height and width), no, CSS alone can't do that; you'll need Javascript.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can you not just float everything left?

Comment: It is already floated left, check out the fiddle and resize the right frame ;) Ok in this case its an inline block but float: left shows the same result.

Comment: @MrLister the width of the blocks are fix and always 400 or a multiple of that. Ist just the height thats trying to kill me, but thanks so far, like i thought :(